# in selenium Maven project java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I setup my project eclipse into intelligent IDE.In my eclipse everything was fine.But in intelligent IDE.I am getting error java.lang.NullPointerException.I am not getting any Idea how to solve

My current Code I run into IDE

```
ChromeDriver wd;


@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   wd = new ChromeDriver();
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
@Test(priority =31 ,retryAnalyzer = Retry.class)
public void AirBNB_add_show_One_Time() throws InterruptedException {
    wd.manage().window().maximize();
    wd.get("http://local.something.io/refine?amenity_keyword=internet&amenities=21&minimum_price=50&maximum_price=200&amount=50-200&order=2&changed_currency=USD&pax=4&date_end=2017-08-30&date_start=2017-08-28&view=grid&sqs=&location_id=&search=Paris%2C+France");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).click();

Thread.sleep(10000);
for (String windows : wd.getWindowHandles()) {

    wd.switchTo().window(windows);
    String CurrentURL = wd.getCurrentUrl();
    if (CurrentURL.startsWith("http://local.alojamiento.io")) {
        wd.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(7000);

        boolean imoverlayadd=wd.findElement(By.xpath("")).isDisplayed();
        boolean airbnb=wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).isDisplayed();
        assertFalse(airbnb,"Airbnb Add will not show After clicking Add one times");
    }}  
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {

    driver.quit();
}
```

When i runthis code i am getting following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at vrs.RentbyownerAutomationFinal.AnalyticsCode(RentbyownerAutomationFinal.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: But same code working perfectly for eclipse

Comment: Can you post the full code .. We wouldnt know what is line number 40 in vrs.RentbyownerAutomationFinal.AnalyticsCode(RentbyownerAutomationFinal.java:40)

Comment: @Raveesh Sharma wd.manage().window().maximize(); in this line i am getting error

Comment: I cant see any reference to your wd variable in the code you posted. Are you sure its initialized ? Probably that is throwing NPE

Comment: Oh .. you modified .. ok ..

Comment: Yes, my code is perfectly running on eclipse.I am getting error for Intelligent IDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153015/discussion-between-zsbappa-and-raveesh-sharma).